# TitanDB not using indexes for query

Tags: indexing, titan

I have created indexes on two properties:

```
mgmt.buildIndex("userId", Vertex.class).addKey(mgmt.makePropertyKey("userId").dataType(Integer.class).make()).buildCompositeIndex();

mgmt.buildIndex("firstNameIndex", Vertex.class).addKey(mgmt.makePropertyKey("firstName").dataType(String.class).make()).buildCompositeIndex();
```

On Gremlin shell i can see the indexes have been created:

```
g.getIndexedKeys(Vertex.class)
==>userId
==>firstName
```

Now when i so query on vertices like simplest one:

```
gremlin> g.V()
18:33:42 WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx  - Query requires iterating over all vertices [()]. For better performance, use indexes
==>v[512]
==>v[256]
```

Or some complex one:

```
gremlin> g.V.has('firstName' ,CONTAINS,'Raj')
18:36:00 WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx  - Query requires iterating over all vertices [(firstName CONTAINS Raj)]. For better performance, use indexes
==>v[512]
```

Why its not using indexes for query.??

And is there any difference between creation of indexes and key indexes.?
Any Explanation will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Based on http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html#index-mixed

> Use a composite index for exact match index retrievals. Composite
>   indexes do not require configuring or operating an external index
>   system and are often significantly faster than mixed indexes.
>
> As an exception, use a mixed index for exact matches when the number
>   of distinct values for query constraint is relatively small or if one
>   value is expected to be associated with many elements in the graph
>   (i.e. in case of low selectivity). Use a **mixed indexes** for numeric
>   range, full-text or geo-spatial indexing. Also, using a mixed index
>   can speed up the order().by() queries.

In your case that it seems you are doing a **full text search** you need to use a mixed index, since composite ones are only used for exact matches.

You can find more info about full text search indices in: http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/index-parameters.html#_full_text_search

I don't see anywhere any difference between indices and key indices. Vertex-centric indices are different than property/key indices. Have a look at the link I provided. Hope this helps!