# TitanDB Defining and Using Indexes

Tags: java, titan, tinkerpop

Using [this](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/current/indexes.html). I am constructing the following index:

```
TitanManagement management = graph.openManagement();

PropertyKey key = management.makePropertyKey("ITEM_IDENTIFIER").dataType(String.class).make();

management.buildIndex("byItemIdentifier", Vertex.class).addKey(key).buildCompositeIndex();

management.commit();
```

However when I run the following query:

```
graph.traversal().V().has("ITEM_IDENTIFIER", "Test");
```

I still get the warning:

```
Query requires iterating over all vertices [(ITEM_IDENTIFIER = Test)]. For better performance, use indexes
```

How can I get TitanDB to use the index in order to speed up the lookups ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I managed to figure out the issue. Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33313641/1457059) providing more info.

The problem is that I assumed that I would use a `CompositeIndex` but after more careful reading of [Chapter 20](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/index-parameters.html), [Chapter 22](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/elasticsearch.html), and [Chapter 28](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/index-admin.html) I was actually wrong. `String` based indexes require a `MixedIndex`.

To get MisedIndexes working with strings I had to first install [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) to enable `String` based indexes. Then I was able to configure my index by replacing:

```
management.buildIndex("byItemIdentifier", Vertex.class).addKey(key).buildCompositeIndex();
```

with

```
management.buildIndex("byItemIdentifier", Vertex.class).addKey(key, Mapping.STRING.asParameter()).buildMixedIndex("search");
```

after doing this the warning disappeared. I am going to do more testing to confirm this worked but for now this seems to have solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your index definition looks reasonable, but there are a couple reasons the index might not be used you should check.

The index has to finish building.

```
mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, "byItemIdentifier").call()
```

Or you need to reindex your existing data

```
mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex("byItemIdentifier"), SchemaAction.REINDEX).get()
```

Note that this latter operation should be completed inside a transaction.

Comment: This has helped me slightly. When I wait for the status `mgmt.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph, "byItemIdentifier").call()` my application stalls with the following message `Some key(s) on index byItemIdentifier do not currently have status REGISTERED: ITEM_IDENTIFIER=ENABLED`. So the problem is with the key.

Comment: Vote up for useful info but the solution required a different approach. Thanks for the assistance.